# Multiply a 180x360 array by a 156-item time-series to get 180x360x156 array?

Tags: matlab, bsxfun

```
bsxfun(@times,RegressIndexFlux.(IndexNames{i}).(FluxNames{j}), Indices.(IndexNames{i}));
```

So my code is above.

The problem with bsxfun is that I get the below error message:

```
Error using bsxfun
Non-singleton dimensions of
the two input arrays must
match each other.
```

So here's the question: is there a way for me to convert the 180x360 array by a timeseries without having to use for loops, if possible? (I'm using many structures of 180x360 arrays here). Basically `RegressIndexFlux` is regressed against the time-series `Indices`, and I'm trying to get a reconstruction of the time-series by only using the regression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have mismatched non-singleton dimensions.  Permute the second argument. Assuming `A` is a `m-by-n` matrix and `B` is a (`p-by-1`) column vector:

```
A = rand(6,5); B = rand(4,1);
% m-by-n @times 1-by-1-by-p => m-by-n-by-p
C = bsxfun(@times,A,permute(B,[3 2 1]));
size(C)
ans =
     6     5     4
```